# Is a nonlinear regression model valid even if it not Homoscedastic?

Tags: regression, model-selection, heteroscedasticity, nonlinear-regression

I have a couple of experimental data sets where I am trying to determine if there is, for each data set, a particular linear/nonlinear regression model that correlates both variables. To this end, I have fitted multiple different models to the data (using Graphpad Prism), determined the respective AICc and selected the lowest valued AICc model as the best model (out of the ones tested).

For the sake of simplicity, I will refer to a single of these data sets, but I am hoping to get a general idea.

[image: Values for variable]

For this particular data set, the model with lowest AICc was a log line (defined as:Y = Slope*log(X) + Yintercept). Following are the results from the statistic analysis (made in GraphPad Prism):

[image: Statistics results]

So, according to these results, the residuals are normal, but there is no homoscedasticity. Does this mean that I should exclude the log line model as being a valid model for this data set? How should I interpret this?

Let me know if you need any more info on my end. I should make a disclaimer that I am not a mathematician, so go easy on me :D

Comment: I suggest you look at a plot of your residuals before anything else. Then another plot of residuals Vs fitted. You will see by yourself instead of thru the prism of statistics.

Comment: The issue here is that I have a couple of hundred of correlations to look at so anything that I could do to make decisions easier would be appreciated. Also, looking at a plot and making a decision based on that doesn't sound too "scientific" (for lack of a better word) to me. The only way to be absolutely sure just by looking at the graph is if we either have an horrible fit or a perfect fit. If its is something in between you will not know

Comment: Because you are trying to learn something ***but you don't know what***, your should really first look at your data first, before trying to fit anything to it. Maybe it will take you a day or two however this investment in time will not be wasted.

Comment: I undestand that I might not know a lot about this subject but I do know what I want to learn, I am not sure how "looking at the data" as you suggest will change any of the questions I had, as they are quite general.

Comment: Sorry if I offended you I really didn't mean to. When I say that you don't know what you are looking for, I really mean you are looking for correlations between variables, but you have no idea (from what I understand in your question) about what you are going to find. Scientific method makes hypothesis then design experiment to test the hypothesis. In your particular problem, one could say you are looking for hypotheses, which can be a preceding step to the part of formulating hypothesis then test it thru experiment.

Comment: Not at all, sorry if I came across as offended, that was not what i was trying to sound like. 
I do have an hypothesis: Variables X and Y are correlated via a log function. It is a simple hypothesis. What I want to understand is if it the lack of Homoscedasticity indicates this model is, in fact, not correct and, therefore, we can state that there is no log function relationship between X and Y.

Comment: The lack of homoscedasticity indicates, as you know, that the variance of the residuals of your fitted model depends on the value of your independent variable(s). It is actually an integral part of your model because (...)

Comment: (...) because a model is not only an equation but also a model of distribution of residuals. Simple linear modelling assumes that the residuals are normally distributed around the predicted value, with constant variance i.e. independent of the predictors. That's actually a model of the residuals. Generalized linear models are an extension of simple linear models, where one can specify the model, or distribution, of the residuals. (...)

Comment: (...) I also learned thru books and professors that slight departure from the assumptions about residuals are often without consequences, because linear models are actually quite robust against it and estimates of parameters might not be so much affected by heteroscedasticity. So even if a test on residuals indicates such departure, look at the plot of residuals against predictor(s) to see if that is completely crazy / biased. From a scientific perspective, I strongly believe one good and well designed plot is at least as relevant as a dozen tests.

Comment: Thank you for this info, that is all that I needed to know! :)

Answer (score -1):

The "significant" p-value doesn't tell you whether departure from homoscedasticity assumptions is hugely violated or only slightly.

In the case on only slight departure, your model could still be useful because the estimates of parameters might not be so much biased after all.

However in the event of huge heteroscedasticity, simple linear model might not be enough.
There are many methods to deal with heteroscedasticity :
- on the first hand, your model might not incorporate an important predictor. Finding which predictor in lacking is then probably very important.
- on the other hand, assuming you have specified the right model, you could try 1) refine the predictors (sometime the scale of a predictor is just too large and that seems to be a common reason for heteroscedasticity. This modifier might perhaps be successfully replaced by another similar but me focused predictor ; 2) use weighted linear modeling with correct weights, that weights more those data points that are within a list variance zone, and give less importance to the high variance zone... ; 3) transform dependent variable so as to try to eliminate artificially the problem of heteroscedasticity (I prefer 1 and 2 because 3 might be difficult to interpret)

All that being said, one good and well designed plot of residuals vs fitted values is as valid (if not more IMO) as any test from a scientific perspective, to identify heteroscedasticity of the residuals.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess, for me, as a person that is usually very fond of statistics, it's kind of hard for me to accept that I just need to look at it and see. I understand what you are trying to say, but I have seen graphs of residuals vs predicted in online tutorials where they are used as an example of "bad" or "good" heteroscedasticity and I just do not see it for the most part. This is why I was looking for a statistic test that could mathematically define this. Does this make sense?

Comment: Of course it does make sense. Tests are tools to help us take decisions. Your test tells that the residuals are not homoscedastic. It's just that it is not per se an indication that your model is bad. It indicates that your model might not capture the whole story. But it might nevertheless be ok. You will need to argument, though, why that's not a problem in your specific case. Or switch to other methods of analysis based on that observation.

Comment: -1 "However in the event of huge heteroscedasticity, simple linear model might not be enough." Linear models tend to badly biased by heteroscedasticity.

Comment: I would like to upvote this answer because it looks like it has good advice, but I'm troubled by references to a "simple linear model" and "linear modeling" in a thread about *nonlinear* models.  This means I can't really be sure how appropriate this answer is or whether what is written is really what you intended to say.